# Adding results of Hadoop job to Hive Table

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, hcatalog, qubole

I have a Map-only job that processes a large text file.  Each line is analyzed and categorized.  MultipleOutputs are used to output each category into separate files.  Eventually all the data gets added to a Hive table dedicated to each category.  My current workflow does the job but is a bit cumbersome.  I am going to add a couple of categories, and thought I might be able to streamline line the process.  I have a couple of ideas and was looking for some input.

Current Workflow:

1. Map-only job divides large file into categories.  The output looks like this:

  categ1-m-00000
  categ1-m-00001
  categ1-m-00002
  categ2-m-00000
  categ2-m-00001
  categ2-m-00002
  categ3-m-00000
  categ3-m-00001
  categ3-m-00002

2. An external (non-Hadoop)  process copies the output files into separate directories for each category.

  categ1/00000
  categ1/00001
  categ1/00002
  categ2/00000
  categ2/00001
  categ2/00002
  categ3/00000
  categ3/00001
  categ3/00002

3. An external table is created for each category and then the data is inserted into the permanent Hive table for that category.

Possible new workflows

- Use Spark to loop through the output files, and based on the file name, insert the data into the appropriate permanent Hive table.
- Use HCatalog to insert the data into the permanent Hive table directly from the Mapper, or perhaps a Reducer or set of Reducers dedicated to each category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For MultipleOutputs set output path to base folder where your hive external tables located.
Then write data into `"<table_name>/<filename_prefix>"`.
And your data will be located in your target tables.

Comment: That worked like a charm!  I can't believe I missed that version of write.